# Strings with spaces in structures

Tags: c++, arrays, string, structure

I need to enter strings `Dept_name` and `Hod` which will include spaces, however cin>> does not allow this and using `getline` gives an insufficient parameters error. What is the easiest way to input a string which is in another array, with spaces? I'm confused because i'm using a structure array but i've learnt that  `getline` requires the string to be in the form of an array as well. Please be patient as i'm new to programming, thank you :)

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
struct department
{
    string Dept_name;
    string Dept_id;
    int No_of_students;
    int NumberOfFacultyMembers;
    string Hod;
};


void readlist(department *v1, int v2);
void updatelist(department *v1, int v2);

int main()
{
    int choice;
    department list[5];

    cout<<"Welcome to Department Section\n";
    cout<<"Enter your choice\n";
    cout<<"Press 1 to take information of Department\n";
    cout<<"Press 2 to Update information of any Department\n";

    cin>>choice;

    if (choice==1)

    {
        readlist(list,5);
    }

    else if (choice==2)

    {
        updatelist(list,5);
    }
    cout<<"Enter your choice\n";
    cout<<"Press 1 to take information of Department\n";
    cout<<"Press 2 to Update information of any Department\n";
    cin>>choice;

    if (choice==1)

    {
        readlist(list,5);
    }

    else if (choice==2)

    {
        updatelist(list,5);
    }

    return 0;
}
void readlist(department *v1, int v2)
{
    for (int i=0; i<v2; i++)
    {
        cout<<"\n\n********** Information of department "<<i+1<<" **********";
        cout<<"\nEnter department name: ";
        cin>>(v1->Dept_name);
        cout<<"\nEnter department ID: ";
        cin>>(v1->Dept_id);
        cout<<"\nEnter number of students: ";
        cin>>(v1->No_of_students);
        cout<<"\nEnter number of faculty members: ";
        cin>>(v1->NumberOfFacultyMembers);
        cout<<"\nEnter HoD's name': ";
        cin>>(v1->Hod);
        v1++;
    }
}
void updatelist(department *v1, int v2)
{
    string id;
    cout<<"Enter Department ID\n";
    cin>>id;
    for (int i=0; i<v2; i++)
    {
        if ((v1->Dept_id)==id)
         {
            cout<<"Enter new number of faculty members\n";
            cin>>(v1->NumberOfFacultyMembers);
            cout<<(v1->Dept_name)<<" now has "<<(v1->NumberOfFacultyMembers)<<" faculty members\n";
         }

        v1++;
    }

}
```

Comment: The easiest way is to use [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and pass it the correct arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example of how to use std::getline:

```
struct department
{
    std::string Dept_name;
    std::string Dept_id;
    int No_of_students;
    int NumberOfFacultyMembers;
    std::string Hod;
};

int main()
{
    department dep;

    std::cout << "Write some text:\n";

    std::getline(std::cin, dep.Hod);

    std::cout << "You wrote: \"" << dep.Hod << "\".\n";
}
```

Using it:

```
Write some text:
Rayscary is a scary ray?
You wrote: "Rayscary is a scary ray?".
```